# Rosjava - Launch another node from within rosjava node

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have an application on my android device that runs a rosjava node (the example pubsub node) on my robot.

Let's say I have another package X, implemented in C++. I create the node using

```
rosrun X Y
```

At the moment pubsub node is started, I want to get Y node started as well. (I assume I do that inside rosjava node)

I don't know how to do that. I appreciate any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59742/rosjava---launch-another-node-from-within-rosjava-node/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're trying to make your nodes run in a specific order. That's generally a bad idea. Instead, a node should simply wait until the system is in the state it expects (e.g. a particular topic is being published).

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0